# Download csv from URL format: https://.../%Y%m%d.csv for a time period once using Python

Tags: python, csv, download

I am new to python and need some help.

I am downloading data from 'https://.../..._20200110.csv'.

I am able to download one file using the code:

```
import requests
import shutil
r = requests.get('https://.../..._20200110.csv', stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open("20200110.csv", 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

How can I download data from 20190131 to 20200102?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Does changing the date in the url not work?

Comment: I don't know how to change the date using code instead of doing it manually.

Comment: Which part of the process are you struggling with?

Comment: The way to change the date in to link. I want to download csv files for a time period, for example form 20090110 to 20110321. But I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: I know, I meant what part of generating/modifying the url programatically is causing you trouble?

Comment: I just don't know how to modify the url. Totally no idea.

Comment: I would recommend doing some research on string formatting in Python, then.

Comment: I tried the following but failed.

Comment: import requests
import shutil
import datetime
dates=[datetime.datetime(2019,1,1)+datetime.timedelta(dval) for dval in range(0,366)];
for dateval in dates:
    r = requests.get('https://www.tfx.co.jp/publication/document/daily_statis_'+dateval.strftime('%Y%m%d')+'.CSV', stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(dateval.strftime('%Y%m%d')+".csv", 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)

Comment: You should add that as an edit to your post, it's very difficult to read code in comments.

Comment: I just found the 'edit' button.

Comment: Did you print the URLs to check them?

Comment: I tried creating a few URLs manually and opening them in my browser, it looks like the documents might not be following a consistent format, although I'm not entirely certain of it.

Comment: For some days the url dose not exit. The format is right but for weekends and sometimes for random days the link dose not exit. Again I do not know how to deal with this problem.

Comment: _Again I do not know how to deal with this problem._ Hint: look at the status code of the requests when the file doesn't exist, versus when it does.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Any idea what's going on with the encoding of the 8th column of every file?

Comment: That's originally in Japanese. It is not 'utf-8' or 'gbk'. I can only get it right by changing my system language into Japanese.

Comment: Oh wow, that’s extreme. What OS are you using?

Comment: It's OS X 10.15.1.

Comment: I may have figured out the encoding issue, are you dead set on using `.raw` and `shutil.copyfileobj()`?

Answer (score 1):

As AMC commented, your answer lies in the roam of string formatting, e.g. using f-strings (python >3.6).

In addition you'll need to loop over dates while accounting for days in the month. As such, you'll want to convert your date string into some sort of date object with which you can count, e.g. `datetime`.

To help you get started: the code below should do what you're after. You will probably want to add some logic/feedback for if files could not be found.

```
import requests
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# enter start/end dates here, convert to datetime object
start_date = datetime.strptime('2009-10-31', '%Y-%m-%d')  # the latter arg defines the format of the given string
end_date = datetime.strptime('2011-01-02', '%Y-%m-%d')

# need to know how many days we need to loop over
day_count = (end_date - start_date).days + 1

# loop over days and download file
for i in range(day_count):
    date_str = (start_date + timedelta(i)).strftime('%Y%m%d')  # convert our datetime obj into the desired string format
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.tfx.co.jp/publication/document/daily_statis_{date_str}.csv', stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(f'{date_str}.csv', 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there something wrong? Using this I just get one csv file called 'date_str'. Can I get csv files for every day in the time priod?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you! I add '{}' for date_str in the sentence 'with open(f'date_str.csv', 'wb') as f:' and problem solved.

Comment: Good catch, f-strings indeed require {} around the variable. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution, which appears to be handling the encoding correctly:

```py
import datetime

import requests

dates = (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 5) + datetime.timedelta(offset) for offset in range(10))

with requests.Session() as req_sess:
    for curr_date in dates:
        date_str = curr_date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        curr_url = f"https://www.tfx.co.jp/publication/document/daily_statis_{date_str}.csv"
        with req_sess.get(curr_url, stream=True) as req:
            if req.status_code == 200:
                req.encoding = 'shift-jis'
                with open(f'../out/{date_str}.csv', 'w') as out_file:
                    out_file.write(req.text)
```

Let me know if anything isn't clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative version based on `f-strings` and `pathlib`. It requires Python 3.6+ though because of `f-strings`:

```py
import requests
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

start = datetime.strptime('20091031', '%Y%m%d')
end = datetime.strptime('20110102', '%Y%m%d')
days = (end - start).days + 1

dates = ((start + timedelta(_)).strftime('%Y%m%d') for _ in range(days))

csvdir = Path('/dir/to/save/files/in')

for date in dates:
    csvfile = f'daily_statis_{date}.csv'

    url = f'https://www.tfx.co.jp/publication/document/{csvfile}'

    print(f'Requesting: {csvfile}')
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    if r.ok:
        print(f'Writing {csvdir/csvfile}')
        (csvdir/csvfile).write_text(r.text)
    else:
        print(f'Error requesting {csvfile}: status code {r.status_code}')
```

Comment: @Helloworld, if possible mark one of the answers as accepted. That will help others with the same question and the answer's author as well.